# Trigger toast from outside React component

Tags: reactjs, toast, primereact

I am using PrimeReact's toast component, whose API looks like this:

```
function App() {
  const toast = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    toast.current.show({
      severity: 'info',
      detail: 'Hellope'
    });
  });

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Toast ref={toast} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I would now like to call `toast.current.show()` from a non-React context. In particular, I have an `http()` utility function through which all HTTP calls are made. Whenever one fails, I would like to show a toast. What are clean/idiomatic ways to achieve this?

Comment: Why isn't your `http()` utility function inside a custom hook?

Comment: I guess I didn't see a reason to put it in one. At the moment, it's a generic Axios-like function that knows nothing about React. What would it mean to have it inside a custom hook and how would that help?

Comment: There are many similar questions with a working answer. I'd suggest to look for promises and async/await or callbacks.

Comment: *I guess I didn't see a reason to put it in one* - you can do it to access toasts for example

Comment: @Konrad, I'm sorry, but I can't quite see how that idea would play out.

Answer (score 5):

I would create a toast context that would allow showing toasts

`toast-context.js`

```
import "primereact/resources/themes/lara-light-indigo/theme.css";
import "primereact/resources/primereact.css";
import { Toast } from "primereact/toast";
import { createContext, useContext, useRef } from "react";

// create context
const ToastContext = createContext(undefined);

// wrap context provider to add functionality
export const ToastContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const toastRef = useRef(null);

  const showToast = (options) => {
    if (!toastRef.current) return;
    toastRef.current.show(options);
  };

  return (
    <ToastContext.Provider value={{ showToast }}>
      <Toast ref={toastRef} />
      <div>{children}</div>
    </ToastContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useToastContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(ToastContext);

  if (!context) {
    throw new Error(
      "useToastContext have to be used within ToastContextProvider"
    );
  }

  return context;
};
```

`index.js`

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";
import { ToastContextProvider } from "./toast-context";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <ToastContextProvider>
      <App />
    </ToastContextProvider>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

`App.js`

```
import { useToastContext } from "./toast-context";

export default function App() {
  // use context to get the showToast function
  const { showToast } = useToastContext();
  const handleClick = () => {
    http(showToast);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>show toast</button>
    </div>
  );
}

// pass showToast callback to your http function
function http(showToast) {
  showToast({
    severity: "success",
    summary: "Success Message",
    detail: "Order submitted"
  });
}
```

Codesanbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-cray-rzrfne?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Oh, I see. I considered passing the toast reference as an argument as well, just without hooks, since I have flexibility to change the implementation of `http()`, i.e. `function http(toast) { ... }`. You see the problem here, though, right? `http()` is used in dozens of places, and I would like to avoid having to either write one `<Toast />` with its reference in every place from which a request is made, or keeping a single `<Toast />` in `<App />` but having to propagate its reference all to all components that need it.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the toast on the window object.

```js
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    window.PrimeToast = toast.current || {};
  }, []);
```

On your fetch or axios handler, use the above object on your error handler

```js
   const fakeUrl = "https://api.afakeurl.com/hello";
   fetch(fakeUrl)
      .then((res) => res.data)
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("error fetching request", err);
        if (window.PrimeToast) {
          window.PrimeToast.show({
            severity: "error",
            summary: "Error calling https",
            detail: "hello"
          });
        }
      });
```

[Updated Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/primereacttoast-non-reactcontext-6spm9z?file=/src/App.js:65-114)

Reference:

1. https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/toast/

Comment: I have the non-React `http()` utility function from which I need to trigger the toast. Hooks can't be called from non-react functions.

Comment: Initialize the toast on the window. On you http() utility inside catch handler trigger the toast.

Comment: Well, no offense, but, I could think of a global variable myself. I was hoping for a better option.

Comment: No worries. Do you have anything on how could we approach this? Anything could help

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution I have been experimenting with, although I have the impression it isn't very idiomatic. I suppose one could look at it as a "micro-frontend" responsible exclusively for showing toasts.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { RefObject, useRef } from 'react';
import { Toast, ToastMessage } from 'primereact/toast';

class NotificationService {
  private toast?: RefObject<Toast>;

  constructor() {
    const toastAppRoot = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.append(toastAppRoot);

    const ToastApp = () => {
      this.toast = useRef<Toast>(null);
      return <Toast ref={this.toast} />;
    };

    ReactDOM.createRoot(toastAppRoot).render(<ToastApp />);
  }

  showToast(message: ToastMessage) {
    this.toast!.current!.show(message);
  }
}

export const notificationService = new NotificationService();
```

The simplicity of its usage is what's really nice of an approach like this. Import the service, call its method. It used to be that simple.

Comment: Quite a unique approach. I wonder how each new instance of `NotificationService` would end up polluting the DOM nodes. Totally depends on the number of instance we have though.

Comment: Typically, a service like this would be a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a solution using events on the `window` object here:
[gist of the solution](https://gist.github.com/Nicoolandgood/a4f162f97eadd22c725dfa943de2de9f)

It works by wrapping the components that need toasts in a `ToastProvider` where the `Toast` component is used and all the logic of toast display is coded. A `useLayoutEffect` adds a listener to "toast" events to `window`.
Then, you can just emit this kind of event on `window` from anywhere in your app it will display a toast (even outside of a component).

The gist above contains code implementing a hook `useToast` and a `toast` object with same purpose functions/methods (show, showInfo, showSuccess, showWarn and showError).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).